# UISearchController in iOS 9 - TextField from UISearchBar clipping out of navigation item

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to get a smooth Searchbar on navigation item on iOS 9, which means I can't use `navigationItem.searchController` property since its only iOS 11 only.

```
class SearchContainerViewController: UITableViewController {
    let dataSource = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

    override public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }

    override public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel?.text = dataSource[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class SearchViewController: UISearchController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

class MyViewController : UIViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {
    lazy var searchButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Search", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(showSearchBar))

    var searchViewController: SearchViewController = {
        let container = SearchContainerViewController()
        let searchController = SearchViewController(searchResultsController: container)

        return searchController
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupSearchController()
        setupSearchButton()
    }

    func setupSearchController() {
        searchViewController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchViewController.searchBar.delegate = self

        searchViewController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchViewController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchViewController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        searchViewController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true

        definesPresentationContext = true
    }

    @objc func showSearchBar() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75) {
            self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchViewController.searchBar
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
            self.searchViewController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    func setupSearchButton() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75) {
            self.navigationItem.titleView = nil
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.searchButton
        }
    }

    //  MARK: Conforms to UISearchResultUpdating

    public func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) { }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        setupSearchButton()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        view.layoutSubviews()
    }
}


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        let newWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        let mainViewController = MyViewController()
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)

        newWindow.backgroundColor = .white
        newWindow.rootViewController = navigationController
        newWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()

        window = newWindow

        return true
    }
}
```

Though the result is kinda disappointing since the textview with StatusBar is clipping out of the navigation item context, there is anything im doing wrong and could've done better?

Appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0):

In before people down voting the question for no reasons, I am going to do something different and answer my own question.

The clipping happened because in both situations the height of the navigationItem were different because of they are somewhat stretchable if put big content in titleView (like a searchBar).

I've set the searchBar from the start on the navigationItem and just toogle their isHidden property when it should be done.

```
    @objc private func activateSearch() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75) {
            self.navigationItem.titleView?.isHidden = false
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
            self.searchController.isActive = true
        }
    }

    private func deactivateSearch() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75) {
            self.navigationItem.titleView?.isHidden = true
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.searchButton
            self.searchController.isActive = false
        }
    }
```